# Push pin on bing map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bing-maps

I am already done push pin on bing map but the issue is more than 100 push pin is not visible on bing map. I have REST api and I am getting data from api and fetch longitude and latitude on map. By the REST api push pin on map is working fine.
But more than 100 pins are not showing on map.
 Is that any limitation for Bing map to allow less than push pins are showing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the static map API although you didn't provide any sample code or explicitly list which API you were using.
If you check the documentation here under the "pushpin limits" section:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
The static maps API only supports 18 pushpins if passed through the URL, or 100 pushpins if passed via POST. This is for performance and practical reasons - more than 100 pins on a small static map would just cover the whole image.
If you want to display more pushpins, you should use the interactive map control, not the static map API.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx